# Docker compose not respecting depends_on when target container is stoped/down

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, failover

I have my `docker-compose.yml` like:

```
version: '3.9'
services:

    app:
        image: whatever:latest
        ports:
            - "8081:8080"
        healthcheck:
            test: "curl -s http://localhost:8080/q/health | grep -q '\"status\": \"UP\"'"
            interval: 5s
            timeout: 5s
            retries: 20

    app-monitor:
        image: whatever:latest
        depends_on:
            app:
                condition: service_healthy
```

This works very well on `docker-compose up -d` . But there's a problem, steps to reproduce:

1. `docker-compose up -d`
2. `docker-compose stop app`
3. `docker-compose start app-monitor` (Starting app-monitor ... done)

Shoudn't step 3 fail?
How do I make service `app-monitor` to fail if the depends_on target service is down?

My purpose here is to make sure all docker-compose services are up and running at all times, in bash would look like:

```
if ! docker-compose start app-monitor &> /dev/null; then
    docker-compose down && docker-compose up -d
fi
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`docker-compose stop` leaves a container in an unusual state, where the container exists but its process isn't running.  In turn `docker-compose start` is only useful with containers in this unusual state.  Since it's not creating new containers, `start` doesn't check `depends_on:` constraints; its assumed that these constraints were already met when the container was created at `docker-compose up` time.

In practice I'd almost never use either `docker-compose stop` or `start`.  (Compare to managing non-container server process with `kill -STOP` and `kill -CONT`, rather than asking your init system to stop or restart the service.)

In normal operation I'd usually depend on `docker-compose up -d` to do the right thing.  You shouldn't manually need to start or stop containers, just run `up`.  If a container isn't in the state described in the `docker-compose.yml` file then Compose will make it so, possibly deleting and recreating the container if necessary.

```bash
# make sure all services are up and running
docker-compose up -d  # no explicit `docker-compose start` or `down`

# update images if necessary
docker-compose pull && docker-compose up -d

# restart the app-monitor
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate app-monitor
```

Comment: But how how would I know that a container stoped on failure using the `app-monitor`. Maybe `restart: unless_stoped`solved this?

Comment: The last command recreates all services :/